# Generating functions from a recursive type

Tags: haskell

Suppose in my application I have a set of functions that have very regular implementations (like specific logging functions). I have a type

```
data ShowFns = 
  { showFn1 :: Int -> Bool -> Double -> String
  , showFn2 :: Double -> Char -> String
  }
```

Both of these could be implemented simply as

```
showFn1' :: Int -> Bool -> Double -> String
showFn1' a b c = show a <> " " <> show b <> " " <> show c

showFn2' :: Double -> Char -> String
showFn2' a b = show a <> " " <> show b

fnCollection :: ShowFns
fnCollection = ShowFns showFn1' showFn2'
```

However, it seems like this repetitive pattern could be derived from a recursive type where all the leaf types have `Show` instances.

I would rather write:

```
fnCollection :: ShowFns
fnCollection = ShowFns toShowFn toShowFn
```

I have a sense this is possible because this is sorta how the Servant machinery works but servant is a bit more complicated and I haven't been able to replicate that machinery down to my simpler example. I have tried a few formulations with open type families but I can't seem to get the type system to reconcile the recursive case `ShowMe` and the base case `()`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking for. Can you try to explain more concretely, with examples? Show a recursive type and how you'd write the show functions recursively by hand. It sounds like you may want to look at generics, but I can hardly guess.

Comment: Because of how `->` is defined, your two functions aren't as similar as they appear. `showFn1 :: a -> b` while `showFn2 :: c -> d` for 4 distinct types `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. The only thing they have in common is what *all* functions have in common: they map an argument type to a return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard trick for implementing variadic functions looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class ShowMe a where showMeRaw :: [String] -> a
instance ShowMe String where showMeRaw = unwords . reverse
instance (Show a, ShowMe b) => ShowMe (a -> b) where
    showMeRaw ss a = showMeRaw (show a : ss)
```

One then normally adds a single top-level helper:

```
showMe :: ShowMe a => a
showMe = showMeRaw []
```

Then your `showFun1'` and `showFun2'` would both be just calls to `showMe`. Try it out in ghci:

```
> (showMe :: Int -> Bool -> Double -> String) 3 True 2.5
"3 True 2.5"
> (showMe :: Double -> Char -> String) 2.5 'a'
"2.5 'a'"
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for! It’s good to know there is a name for this as well. Thank you for being persistent in asking for clarifications.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not super sure I understand the setup. I'm going to make a few assumptions:

1. `data ShowMe a b = ShowMe a b`
2. You want a new class which shows the two parts of a `ShowMe`, separating them by a space, so that for example `showFn1` and `showFn2` can be implemented just by dispatching to the method of this new class.
3. `ShowFns` and `fnCollection` were red herrings, part of an XY-problem, or thinkos, and can be completely ignored.

Under these assumptions, here is how I would proceed:

```
class SpacedString a where spacedString :: a -> String
instance SpacedString () where spacedString _ = ""
instance (Show a, SpacedString b) => SpacedString (ShowMe a b) where
    spacedString (ShowMe a b) = show a <> " " <> spacedString b
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> spacedString (ShowMe (3 :: Int) (ShowMe True (ShowMe 2.5 ())))
"3 True 2.5 "
> spacedString (ShowMe 2.5 (ShowMe 'a' ()))
"2.5 'a' "
```

The extra trailing space can be eliminated if necessary by making the class method produce a list of strings and having a single top-level helper function that combines `unwords` and the class method.

...it all seems a bit perverse, though, given how much less boilerplate code there is and how many fewer nested parentheses there are in this version:

```
> unwords [show (3 :: Int), show True, show 2.5]
"3 True 2.5"
> unwords [show 2.5, show 'a']
"2.5 'a'"
```

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for because the values to be shown are not fixed.

Comment: @Asa Can you elaborate a little bit on why that changes anything? `spacedString` -- and the `unwords`+list construction version -- both still work fine if the values chosen are dynamically determined rather than literals.

Comment: If it helps the `fnCollection` is part of application state and the functions in it may be called many times with different values over the life of the application. The simple way to implement this is to just implement the functions in the collection by hand, but their implementations are so regular that I would rather abstract that away if possible.

Comment: @Asa I see nothing incompatible between this clarification and anything in my answer.

Comment: The assumption #1 requires that `ShowMe`s hold the fixed values to be constructed. In fact, I don't intend them to ever be constructed and instead be a structure that gets mapped to `->`

Comment: @Asa Ah, got it. Okay. So there's still a few things about the setup I don't understand, then. Let's start here: why does `ShowMe` exist at all (why not just use `->`)?

Comment: Because I think there is a middleman abstraction necessary for the solution of the problem, but maybe it was a confusing addition to my question. Let me rephrase it.